# How make query based on Index array in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my case I want to apply filter based on **"role"**. I want only user which have role name is "ashish". I have try to set .indexOn rule in database but I can not get result. My database structure like below
[image]

And exported json for single user like below :

```
    {
  "email" : "ashish.com",
  "firebaseToken" : "fZb3Oh7SAuc:",
  "role" : [ "ashish", "parmar" ],
  "uid" : "3S8ZPyDxsAgEiFailICZMA9m5WG3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would not recommend you to use filter on index as you don't know which index of the array have the value of the role. I would recommend using the data structure below instead.

```
{
  "users": {
    "uid001": {
      "email": "example01@gmail.com",
      "role": {
        "ashish": {
          "userRole": "ashish"
        },
        "parmar": {
          "userRole": "parmar"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "userRole": {
    "ashish": {
      "uid001": {
        "userID": "uid001"
        }
      },
      "uid002": {
        "userID": "uid002"
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

By using userRole you can make query on which uid had the specific role.